# Insert Data into multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider two tables `User` and  `UserDetails`

- User (UserID,Name,Password)
- UserDetails(UserID,FullName, Mobile Number,EMail)

First I will enter details into `User` table

Then Afterwards I wish to enter details into `UserDetails` Table with respect to primary key of first table i.e., `UserID` which is autoincremented.

consider this scenario..

User: (101, abc, xyz), (102,asd,war)
Now i want to store details in second table with respect to Primary key where `UserID= 102`

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You are so vague. Do you need help creating insert for one row? because if you can insert into `user` you also can insert into `userdetail`

Comment: Are you looking for [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)?

Comment: Why split that data into two tables to begin with?  Unless there is a relationship to be expressed (i.e. user can have many emails or many phone numbers), this make no sense. This does not appear to be your case (unless a user can have more than one `FullName`).

Comment: @HannoBinder Agreed and if you want one:many relationships to email or phone number, then I would suggest having separate email and phone number tables that each relate to the user table via user id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start over with the design. Here is a **start** that runs through and doesn't blow up. Do the same for email. Keep data normalized and don't cause unnecessary lookups. When you have a lot of constraints, it is a sign that you care about the quality of your data. Not that you don't without constraints, if they are un-constrainable.

We all read on the internet how we should keep `main` info in one table and `details` in another. Nice as a broad brush stroke. But yours does not rise to that level. Yours would have way too many tables. See `Note1` at bottom about  about Entities. See `Note2` at bottom about performance. See any of us with any broad or specific question you may have.

```
create table user
(   userId int auto_increment primary key,
    fullName varchar(100) not null
    -- other columns
);

create table phoneType
(   phoneType int auto_increment primary key, -- here is the code
    long_description varchar(100) not null
    -- other columns
);

create table userPhone
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    userId int not null,
    phone varchar(20) not null,
    phoneType int not null,
    -- other columns
    CONSTRAINT fk_up_2_user FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES user(userId),
    CONSTRAINT fk_up_2_phoneType FOREIGN KEY (phoneType) REFERENCES phoneType(phoneType)
);
```

`Note1:`

I suspect that your second table as you call it is really a third table, as you try to bring in missing information that really belongs in the Entity.

### Entities

Many have come before you crafting our ideas as we slug it out in design. Many bad choices have been made and by yours truly. A good read is third normal form (3NF) for data normalization techniques.

`Note2:`

Performance. Performance needs to be measured both in real-time user and in developer problem solving of data that has run amok. Many developers spend significant time doing data patches for schemas that did not enforce data integrity. So factor that into performance, because those hours add up in those split seconds of User Experience (UX).

Comment: I would finish it thru but you have your answer with someone else. Design seems to be of no conern. Good luck

Comment: I am not doing this for the points or nod of it being right for you. It's for those that follow, and read at 1am with red-eyes too. I will continue my Answer then and give you some more quality I hope

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:-

```
INSERT INTO userDetails
(SELECT UserID, Name FROM User WHERE USerID= 102), 'Mob_No', EMail;
```

Comment: Perhaps I can help you understand. The OP doesn't have the rep @ 4 to downvote. So you are at -1 until I come along and make it -2. You have gained 2000 pts on the stack, not exactly a newcomer. Part of your responsibility is to steer the OP in the right direction, not slam a quick answer down for points and run away. There is no insight given into how ridiculous his idea is. Did you ever stop to think that his 2nd table as he called it is actually a 3rd table, probably because he has his entity data splattered all over the place? You might not see it as a responsibility, but many of us do.

Comment: And a proper response is not He asked a question, I answered it. Don't play that card.